# How to paint in multi-windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to ask how to paint lines in multi-windows. To be more exactly, I want to open multi-windows and paint something onto them.

In the following code, I want to draw 4 lines in 4 windows respectively. One line in one window. But it shows me only the last painting result, and only one window is shown.

I have tried a lot by myself, but all failed. Could anyone please help me out? Thanks very much in advance!

The code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

lines = [[1, 1, 100, 100], [10, 10, 400, 400], [20, 20, 600, 600], [60, 60, 10, 10]]  #I want to paint 4 lines.

class Plot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Plot, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot(list)
    def getvalue(self, list_plotline):
        print("\n", list_plotline)
        self.line_start_x = list_plotline[0]
        self.line_start_y = list_plotline[1]
        self.line_end_x = list_plotline[2]
        self.line_end_y = list_plotline[3]
        print("plot line: ", self.line_start_x, self.line_start_y, self.line_end_x, self.line_end_y)

        self.setFixedHeight(600)
        self.setFixedWidth(600)

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()

        qp.begin(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(self.line_start_x, self.line_start_y, self.line_end_x, self.line_end_y)
        qp.end()

class MyApp(QWidget):
    signal_plot = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.plotter = Plot()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("plot 4 lines in 4 windows", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        for i in range(len(lines)):  #use for loop to control
            self.signal_plot.connect(self.plotter.getvalue)
            self.signal_plot.emit(lines[i])
            self.signal_plot.disconnect(self.plotter.getvalue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to use signals, in this case it is not necessary, also if you want to store the points do not use n variables but only one that is a `QLine`.

You say: *4 window* but you are only creating a `Plot()`, you must create 4:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

lines = [[1, 1, 100, 100], [10, 10, 400, 400], [20, 20, 600, 600], [60, 60, 10, 10]]  #I want to paint 4 lines.

class Plot(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Plot, self).__init__(parent)
        self.line = QLine()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)

    def setPoints(self, points):
        self.line = QLine(*points)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(self.line)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.plots = [Plot(self) for i in range(len(lines))]
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("plot 4 lines in 4 windows", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        for plot, line in zip(self.plots, lines):  #use for loop to control
            plot.setPoints(line)
            plot.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

With Signals:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

lines = [[1, 1, 100, 100], [10, 10, 400, 400], [20, 20, 600, 600], [60, 60, 10, 10]]  #I want to paint 4 lines.

class Plot(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Plot, self).__init__(parent)
        self.line = QLine()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)

    @pyqtSlot(list)
    def setPoints(self, points):
        self.line = QLine(*points)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(self.line)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    signal_plot = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.plots = [Plot(self) for i in range(len(lines))]
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("plot 4 lines in 4 windows", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        for plot, line in zip(self.plots, lines):  #use for loop to control
            self.signal_plot.connect(plot.setPoints)
            self.signal_plot.emit(line)
            self.signal_plot.disconnect(plot.setPoints)
            plot.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I actually prefer to use signal+slot because I have to transfer more complicated data into paint-class. Would you please show me how to use signal+slot for this problem? Besides, using your code, if I close the main-window, the 4 sub-windows remain open. I actually want to close all 4 sub-windows by closing the main-window.

Comment: @rtt0012 
okay, but for this I need you to answer the following: let's say that the windows are open which action you indicate so that it is drawn in a specific window.

Comment: @rtt0012 
Now solve the second problem, that is, if you close the main window the secondary windows will be closed

Comment: I dont quite understand your comment. :-(  This is what I could imagine: Your code above  shows the result I want to have. There is no need to specify which line is drawn in which sub-window. I prefer to use signal+slot. And the 4 sub-windows can be closed one-by-one (as your code shows), but they can also be closed together by closing the main-window. Thank you so much again!

Comment: I should have reload the page to see your second comment. Great! Thank! Would you please show me how to use signal+slot?

Comment: @rtt0012 see my answer, although I think that you are using the signals and the slots in an incorrect way, but if you wish, I show you.